# CentOS 7 Installation Failed

Tags: centos, system-installation

After hearing the news that CentOS 7 had been published, I decided to install it on my computer. I downloaded the ISO image from the CentOS official website (the one named `CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-DVD.iso`) and then burned it onto a USB drive by using a tool named UltraISO.

After that, I rebooted my computer and pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> to choose my boot device. (My GIGABYTE motherboard uses <kbd>F12</kbd> to choose a boot device.) I chose this: `UEFI: hp v245o 1100`, where `hp v245o 1100` is the USB name, and I suppose this is a so-called *EFI boot from USB*. After that, three menu selections are presented:

1. Install CentOS 7,
2. Test this media & install CentOS 7,
3. and Troubleshooting -->.

At first I decided to choose option 1 to let it display all its running messages, so I typed <kbd>e</kbd> and here is what I get:

```
set params 'Install CentOS 7'
linuxefi /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=CentOS\x207\x20x86_64 quiet
initrdefi /images/pxeboot/initrd.img
```

So I removed the `quiet` param and pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> to start, then I got this:

[image: fb error]

I have no idea what the fb is, and the installation process just stopped there.

So I decided to try the 3rd option (the `Troubleshooting -->` one) with no luck; I still cannot install this CentOS 7 and I got something like:

```
> [7.471771] scsi 0:0:0:0: alua: not attached
> [7.474665] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] no Caching mode page found
> [7.474682] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
> dracut-initqueue[685]: Warning: Could not boot
> dracut-initqueue[685]: Warning: /dev/root does not exist
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: "fb" is the framebuffer -- but I do not think that is your problem.  I'd guess it's UEFI, [although it should be supported](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/UEFI).

Comment: ...but it's not clear whether you need to do anything special to make it work.

Comment: So you mean I can do nothing but wait for CentOS team to fix this problem?

Comment: I don't know -- I don't have an answer for you, I was just clarifying what the "fb" issue is about and that it is probably not the problem.  People on `#centos` IRC say that it should support UEFI without any special effort, so that may be a wrong guess.

Comment: @Christopher - the edit you've made 2 times is breaking the display of the image that the OP included. Please stop doing that edit, it's not correct.

Comment: you mean I should not delete the 'quiet' parameter to install the CentOS? but if not, I can see nothing but a stopped 8 penguin picture on the display. So do you have any suggestions about how to deal with this?

Answer (score 12):

I think you must make bootable usb using `dd` command (if your iso is in home directory):

First unmount (*not* eject) the usb: `sudo umount /dev/sdb1`

Then, write the image to the disk:

```
sudo dd bs=4M if=CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-Everything.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Then it will not show `/dev/root` does not exist.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. Switched from unetbootin to dd (provided by cygwin on windows).

Comment: This worked like a charm. Switched from Rufus here.

Comment: I think that `sudo umount /dev/sdb` . Please explain for me!

Comment: Just in case you have plugged in your USB drive and you have no idea where it is mounted, but you can open the drive and browse the contents. do the following:
1) In the USB's folder, press Ctrl+L to see the path where the contents are. Example might be: `/run/media/george/the-disk`
2) `cat /proc/mounts` and look where the above folder in (1) is mounted. The location will precede the path from (1). Example: `/dev/sdc1`. 
3) From there, follow this answer.

Comment: However, note that this method did not work for me on VMware11. Plugging back the USB on Windows asked me to format my USB. When booting into my USB, the system hung up on a blinking cursor.

Answer (score 5):

`/dev/root` is missing.

This can often be caused by a mismatched label or `/dev/sdXx` root device when booting from USB.

When the dracut shell becomes available, create a directory:

```
mkdir /mnt/
```

Mount different block devices until you have found the one that contains the USB installer(this typically doesn't happen on true/Virt CDROM mounts).

Once you find the `/dev/` for the USB (for instance, if your system reads it as HDD, it might be `/dev/sdd1`), perform the command `blkid` on the device:

```
blkid /dev/sdd1
```

This should tell you the UUID of the block device, you will want to write this down.

Once written down somewhere you can use it, reboot the system. When the grub installer boot options menu loads, press "e" to edit the grub kernel parameters.

From here, move to the end of the line, remove `quiet` so you have an idea why the install fails. Then change the part like:

some boot parameters maybe efi, maybe bios : `LABEL=THELABELYOU\X04HAD`

To:

some boot parameters maybe efi, maybe bios : `UUID="THEUUID-YOUWROTEDOWN"`

Then press ctrl+x to boot with those parameters, hopefully it should work.

Comment: I've been search and searching for an answer for hours and this did it for me.  The -volid wasn't correct in the ISO I created.  That is, it was different than the isolinux.cfg file.  THANK YOU.

Answer (score 3):

I have not installed CentOS 7 myself yet, but you can try

```
linuxefi /images/pxeboot/vmlinuz inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=CentOS\x207\x20x86_64 quiet nomodeset
```

i.e: append 'nomodeset'

If that works, I would blacklist Nouveau after install.

Comment: Hi, after adding this "nomodeset", I can get through the fb process, but then I got a warning which said that /dev/root does not exist. Any suggestion about this?

Comment: Is this happening while booting from the USB device? Found this article that seems to explain what is happening. The article has since been removed but here it is in a web archive: [dont-use-universal-usb-stick-writers](http://web.archive.org/web/20140701065613/http://www.happyassassin.net/2014/02/04/more-on-booting-a-practical-fedora-uefi-guide-and-dont-use-universal-usb-stick-writers/)
If booting from a DVD/CDROM is not an option perhaps you need to look into disabling UEFI.

Comment: The installer failed to find the iso root, this is not about the video settings.

Answer (score 1):

add `hd:/dev/sdb1`  <- to your U disk device name.

Comment: One-line answers are often not the most helpful. If you believe in this solution's relevance, consider expanding your answer to include an explanation or documentation explaining or supporting your solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) has never failed me, you can use it to create a bootable USB drive you can install from.

Comment: It failed me countless times.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a virtual CD. The installer looks up the drive based on the label that contains spaces (\x20). In my case, the installer could not find the virtual CD. I changed the command line (press TAB) to DRIVE=hd:/dev/sr0

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this issue when netbooting the install over PXE. I solved the problem by removing `ksdevice=eth0` parameter from kernel command line. This setting worked with RHEL6, but caused newer versions to fail.

Answer (score -1):

I had problems with several USB image writers, but [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) worked for me.