# /dev/root does not exist in CentOS 7

Tags: boot, system-installation, centos

I get this error message when trying to install CentOS 7 from an USB device:

> /dev/root does not exist in CentOS 7

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It means you don't have a root filesystem.  That *probably* has something to do with trying to install from USB; e.g. if the initramfs doesn't have the drivers to mount from there.

Comment: that means when you created the bootable USB all the information needed for the root wasn't put onto the device. you need to recreate the USB bootable drive. What program are you using to create the boot USB

Comment: I posted an answer to this over on this page, it should work for this too. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141515/centos-7-installation-failed/209515#209515

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Win32 Disk Imager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) on Windows or dd to write the ISO to the USB stick on Linux/OSX.

```
dd if=CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-NetInstall.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=8m
```

I've recently used the first and it booted fine after doing that.

Comment: It's worked. I used Win32 Disk Imager. thank you.

Comment: How do you install it if you have linux and not windows?

Comment: Can you please  what the command does differently from other means of copying?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

`fdisk -l`  -- to show you all the disk available to use, choose your external pendrive

```
dd if="absolute location to your .iso file" of="absolute path shown with above command output"
```

For me, I am on the exact path of my distribution ISO file so I used

`dd if=CentOS.iso of=/dev/sdb2` -- sdb2 is my external pendrive

Bingo !!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing it. Recently for Centos newer versions, most of the USB bootable disk creating applications has reported undefined behavior when they are created and booted form USB disks.(Like Universal USB installer, YUMI multiboot etc.)  [See here](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey)

So better to use `dd` command as @darkorbor other Windows or unix tools. Most of are mentioned in the link I provided up here

`dd if=CentOS-7.0-1406-x86_64-NetInstall.iso of=/dev/sdb`

here , `of=/dev/sdb` should be your USB stick and should be given as the disk only. Not as a partition(not sdb1,sdb2 etc.). you can check the progress of dd  by doing as below.(Quoted from [See here](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/06/show-progress-during-dd-copy.html))

First, find out the process id of the dd process by running the following in the new virtual terminal.

```
$ pgrep -l '^dd$'
8789 dd
$
```

To send the USR1 signal to the dd prcoess:

```
$ kill -USR1  8789
$
```

Note that as soon as the USR1 signal is detected, dd will print out the current statistics to its STDERR.

```
$ dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/null bs=1K count=100
0+14 records in
0+14 records out
204 bytes (204 B) copied, 24.92 seconds, 0.0 kB/s
```

After reporting the status, dd will resume copying. You can repeat the above kill command any time you want to see the interim statistics. Alternatively, you can use the watch command to execute kill at a set interval.

```
$ watch -n 10 kill -USR1 8789
```

Thank you